# Animated focus for input in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am beginner webdeveloper.
I write project with Bootstrap 4.

I have this html:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque
                        
                        
                            03
                        
                    
                    Baza wiedzy

And CSS:

```
.boxes .box3 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/img/slide3.jpg");
  color: white;
  height: 872px;
}

.boxes-scan {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 290px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-scan {
    width: 370px;
  }
}

.boxes-caption-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: 60%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .boxes-caption-text {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-caption-text {
    width: 45%;
    padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
  }
}

.boxes-search-box {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.boxes-caption-number {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .boxes-caption-number {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-caption-number {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px 50px 0 0;
  }
}

.boxes-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-title {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}

.boxes-title .form-control::placeholder {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.boxes-title .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.boxes-title .form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.boxes-title .form-control {
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
}

.boxes-title .form-control:focus {
  color: white;
}

.boxes-title input {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.boxes-arrow {
  width: 55px;
  height: 13px;
  background-image: url("/img/white-arrow.png");
}

.boxes-show-search-ico {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boxes .border-3 {
  border-width: 3px !important;
}



.boxes .box3 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/img/slide3.jpg");
  color: white;
  height: 872px;
}

.boxes-scan {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 290px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-scan {
    width: 370px;
  }
}

.boxes-caption-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: 60%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .boxes-caption-text {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-caption-text {
    width: 45%;
    padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
  }
}

.boxes-search-box {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.boxes-caption-number {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .boxes-caption-number {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-caption-number {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px 50px 0 0;
  }
}

.boxes-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .boxes-title {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}

.boxes-title .form-control::placeholder {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.boxes-title .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.boxes-title .form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.boxes-title .form-control {
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
}

.boxes-title .form-control:focus {
  color: white;
}

.boxes-title input {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.boxes-arrow {
  width: 55px;
  height: 13px;
  background-image: url("/img/white-arrow.png");
}

.boxes-show-search-ico {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boxes .border-3 {
  border-width: 3px !important;
}
```

My preview: https://ibb.co/wB4qht5

I have small problem with my input.

I would like to make an animation in input (focus), after clicking on input the text "czego szukasz" would come up. I mean something like here: https://cutt.ly/Sg6bCs1 (imie, nazwisko, numer telefonu itp).

How can I do this?

Comment: You should provide a part of code necessary to reproduce your problem. Your question should be more specific. You can find tutorials on the web, on SO we don't teach you how to do things like that from scratch. Did you try to do that by yourself? Can you show us what did you try?

Comment: yes i tried to do it myself. So far, I have achieved what I have pasted above :( I don't know how to do this animation

Comment: You pasted a lot of CSS styles here, nothing else. You should paste only that part of your code (HTML too) which is required to show the problem and your attempt to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

To create "floating" label you can set your `<label>` position to absolute and use CSS3 transitions to move and scale it when input is focused or valid (you can use a simple script to check if your inputs are not empty and add a class instead of using CSS pseudo classes - you cannot do that using pure CSS). Remember to enclose your `<input>` and `<label>` elements in a container and set it's position to `relative`. That's actually what they did in the example from your Question.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.inputContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.inputContainer input {
  padding: 18px 10px 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.inputContainer label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 10px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.inputContainer input:focus+label,
.inputContainer input:valid+label {
  transform: translateY(-15px) scale(.625);
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
  <input type="text" id="search" required />
  <label for="search">Czego szukasz</label>
</div>
```